# error when try use skype api with fiddler and script

Tags: botframework

i'm use azure bot api to get token and send message. i'm got token with https://login.microsoftonline.com/botframework.com/oauth2/v2.0/token. but when i try send message (https://smba.trafficmanager.net/apis/v2/conversations/19:9bd02cbc624c44428e12804d321bb705@thread.skype/activities/) - connection closed for fiddler and powershel script but i can send with postman.

can anybody help me understood, how send this post reguest with fidler and script

```
Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1Qi...
```

Content-Type: application/json
Host: smba.trafficmanager.net

```
{
"type": "message",
"from": {
    "id": "28:f1e97c1e-decd-4fac-aecd-2b667fa620af",
    "name": "TestBotNewVeloxy"
},
"conversation": {
    "id": "19:9bd02cbc624c44428e12804d321bb705@thread.skype"
},
"recipient": {
    "id": "28:f1e97c1e-decd-4fac-aecd-2b667fa620af",
    "name": "TestBotNewVeloxy"
},
"text": "test7777"
```

}

Answer (score 1):

if you have same problem - ***need add tls 1.2***